# Python and Beautifulsoup: strange behaviour with findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup        = BeautifulSoup(html)
boxes       = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : re.compile(r'\bmixDesc\b') })
```

I think I got only boxes of class 'mixDesc'.

So I'm debugging to be sure

```
count = 0
for box in boxes :
    count = count + 1

    print "JWORG box {0}".format(count)
    print "JWORG box len {0}".format(len(box))
    print box
```

I've only 10 divs with `mixDesc` class in the parsed html file

But I got 30 boxes and a lot (20 out  of 30) are printed as

```
[]
```

Can you explain why this happens? Why findAll grab this empty tags ? 
Or ... What else mistake have I take ?

EDIT 1:

I'm using this to program a xbmc plugin, so I'm using the only version available to me

EDIT 2:

I cannot copy/paste all of html, but I'm scraping this page: http://www.jw.org/it/video/?start=70

So you can see html source to help me.

EDIT 3: 
this is my xbmc log, please not I printed even a counter and len(box)

```
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box 1
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box len 5
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: [<div class="syn-img sqr mixDesc">
                                            <a href="/it/cosa-dice-la-Bibbia/famiglia/bambini/diventa-amico-di-geova/cantici/120-felice-chi-mette-in-pratica-ci%C3%B2-che-ode/" class="jsDownload jsVideoModal jsCoverDoc" data-jsonurl="/apps/TRGCHlZRQVNYVrXF?output=json&amp;pub=pksn&amp;fileformat=mp4&amp;alllangs=1&amp;track=120&amp;langwritten=I&amp;txtCMSLang=I" data-coverurl="/it/cosa-dice-la-Bibbia/famiglia/bambini/diventa-amico-di-geova/cantici/120-felice-chi-mette-in-pratica-ci%C3%B2-che-ode/" data-onpagetitle="Cantico 120: Felice chi mette in pratica ciÃ² cheÂ ode" title="Play o download | Cantico 120: Felice chi mette in pratica ciÃ² cheÂ ode" data-mid="1102013357">
                                            <span class="jsRespImg" data-img-type="sqr" data-img-size-lg="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357.art/1102013357_univ_sqr_lg.jpg" data-img-size-md="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357.art/1102013357_univ_sqr_md.jpg" data-img-size-sm="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357.art/1102013357_univ_sqr_sm.jpg" data-img-size-xs="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357.art/1102013357_univ_sqr_xs.jpg"></span></a><noscript><img src="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357_I/1102013357_univ_sqr_xs.jpg" alt="" /></noscript>

                                            <div style="display:none;" class="jsVideoPoster mid1102013357" data-src="http://assets.jw.org/assets/m/ijw13pk/1102013357/ijw13pk_id-1102013357.art/1102013357_univ_lsr_lg.jpg" data-alt=""></div>
                                            </div>]
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box 2
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box len 7
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: []
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box 3
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: JWORG box len 7
20:27:54 T:5356  NOTICE: []
```

EDIT 4:

Ok, there 30 divs, because the're nested, but WHY are they empty? and how to filter these out ?

Comment: At least, you'd better use `BeautifulSoup4` and `find_all()`.

Comment: I'm using python to program a plugin on XBMC. I cannot copy/paste all of html but I'm scraping this page: http://www.jw.org/it/video/?start=70

Comment: Could you paste in the full output of your three line `for` loop?

Comment: Soap could be beautiful too, huh? (watch the title) :)

Comment: LOL, fixed. I do this error even when writing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default `findAll()` performs recursive search and since there are nested div contains `bmixDesc` class - you are getting these results.

Pass `recursive=False` to the `findAll` and search for divs inside the parent div with `id=videosIndexList`.

And, also, `BeautifulSoup3` is no longer maintained -  switch to [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and use [find_all()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

Here's what the code should look like (using `BeautifulSoup4`):

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.jw.org/it/video/?start=70'))

div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'videosIndexList'})
boxes = div.find_all("div", { "class" : re.compile(r'\bmixDesc\b')}, recursive=False)

for box in boxes:
    print box.text
```

This will get you only top-level divs (10 boxes).

Comment: but WHY are the nested div printed as empty ... ?

Comment: `soup.findAll("div", { "class" : re.compile(r'\bmixDesc\b') }, recursive = False) ` is giving me ZERO result. Also, I've NOT choice for bs version, I've only the v3 in the xbmc environment

Comment: @realtebo nope, you should call `findAll` on the `div` with `videosIndexList` id (see my example).

Comment: @realtebo it will give you 10 top-level boxes.

Comment: but tell me WHY this happens, please. I'll try to start from a level up, as you said

Comment: @realtebo this is because some nested divs contain no elements, see for example `<div class="syn-img sqr mixDesc noImage"></div>` in the page source.